# Looking into an uninitialized property of an Object in c++

Tags: c++, class, properties

Hey Guys i wondered what the Console would show in this simple Code in C++

```
using namespace std;

class Tier {
public:
    string name;
};

int main()
{
    Tier Affe;
    cout << Affe.name << endl;
}
```

I come from C# and know that an "null"-Error would be thrown. But in C++ the Console shows nothing. When debugging the property is "".

Does this mean that the property "name" is referenced to a nullpointer? 
Thinking of creating an object from the class "Tier", there would be allocated memory with the size of the class. So the property "name" of the object would be allocated in the memory, too.

Why is the debugger showing "" then. In my oppinion where should be some random data, which was in the memory section before...

Comment: Not everything is a pointer in C++, you know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be empty, because the default constructor for `std::string` is to construct an empty string

See constructor 1 here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string

> 1) Default constructor. Constructs empty string (zero size and
>   unspecified capacity)

Therefore there would merely be an empty line (the newline coming from `std::endl`)

If you were later to assign a value to your string member

```
Affe.name = "foo";
```

then an allocation would occur, sufficient memory to store `"foo"` and a null terminator would be allocated.

Comment: would this fact apply to blittable datatypes like int, too?

Comment: No - `int` is a fundamental type, and reading from an uninitialised int is undefined behaviour

Comment: @Pepelee: What is a *blittable* data type?  My understanding is that the hardware that performs blitting is type insensitive.  It only blits an area of memory.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I assumed he meant [POD](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/PODType)

Answer (score 2):

Here there is no "null" error or the like because nothing is null.  In C#, your Affe.name would be a pointer to something (or to nothing).  In C++, it is not a pointer.  It is a VALUE.  For it to be a pointer, you would need to declare it specially as such:

```
class TierContainingPointer {
public:
    string* name;
};
```

Note the *.  Creating an instance of TierContainingPointer would leave you with a "name" pointing to nothing useful, as you have imagined.

But creating an instance of your Tier gives you a full string object that has its own members inside the Tier object.  You imagine the Tier containing a pointer to a string, but instead the Tier contains the actual member data of the string.  The string is embedded in the Tier (though one or more of the string class' own members may be a pointer itself).

Ah, and to address the remainder of the question (though another answer has already done it):  When the "name" instance inside the Tier is created (during the Tier's own creation), its default constructor is run.  And the string class' default constructor leaves the string storing the text "".